# If any value is present in a column of Dataframe, change the value to 1 else insert 0

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with about 1000 rows and 1000 columns. What I want to do is that if any value is present in any cell of the dataframe then change the value to 1 or else put a 0 in that cell. I am programming in R so a R code would be appreciated. I don't want the value of the T column to change but only for the rest of the columns to change.

For example

I have a dataframe like this :

T  A  B  C  D

1  29 90 0  100

2  30 12 76 0

3  0  12 0  32

convert it to :

T  A  B  C  D

1  1  1  0  1

2  1  1  1  0

3  0  1  0  1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ignore the first column, you could combine it with a simple modification of akrun's first solution. For example,

```
data.frame(df[, 1, drop=FALSE], +(df[,-1] != 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can convert to a logical matrix and coerce it to `integer`

```
df1 <- +(df != 0)
```

Or with `replace`

```
replace(df, df != 0, 1)
```

If we need to do this without taking the first column

```
df[-1] <- +(df[-1] != 0)
```

---

Or with `sapply`

```
+(sapply(df, `!=`, 0))
```

---

In `tidyverse`, we can use `mutate_all`

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
          mutate_all(~ as.integer(. != 0))
```

Comment: Hey I'm sorry but I made some changes to the question. Can you help me with this ?

Comment: @Rcoder98723 updated the post.  I posted the solution `df != 0` first here.